# Проблема с отправкой двойных запросов к Базе Данных при заходе на страницу

Tags: php, mysql, cloudflare

сталкиваемся в последние месяцы с проблемой отправки двойных запросов на изменение в базе данных из за этого возникают ошибки = двойные выполнения одного и того же действия
К примеру:
При заходе на определенную страницу скриптом идет запрос в базу данных на сравнение с текущим временем
Если настоящее время больше чем то что в определенной строке в базе данных происходит некое действие с базой данных
Если одновременно в ту же секунду на одну и ту же страницу заходят два разных пользователя и к примеру один зашел на  полсекунды раньше, то идет запрос в БД и из за задержки нашего сервера зарез полсекунды заходит другой участник и скрипт не получив ответ от предыдущего и не сделав изменения отправляет точно такой же запрос и в итоге они обрабатываются сервером и получается двойные изменения.
POST GET - на этой странице нет. Зашел - идет запрос в бд при определенных условиях идут изменения в бд.
подключен cloudflare

Comment: *скрипт не получив ответ от предыдущего и не сделав изменения отправляет точно такой же запрос и в итоге они обрабатываются сервером и получается двойные изменения* То есть ты САМ отправляешь два запроса... ну и кто тебе поможет в этой ситуации? Скрипт ОБЯЗАН получить ответ от сервера (либо сообщение, что сервер недостижим), проанализировать его, и только в случае ошибки выполнения запроса по восстановимой причине - пробовать выполнить запрос повторно.

Comment: Нет. Я не сам отправляю два запроса.
есть страница она доступна всем зарегистрированным участникам
у нас сейчас к примеру одновременно 300 человек сидит
и два РАЗНЫХ человека заходят на одну и ту же страницу в ту же милисекунду почти

Comment: Вы пишете "скрипт не получив ответ от предыдущего и не сделав изменения отправляет точно такой же запрос". Т.е. это один экземпляр скрипта, который посылает запрос повторно, так? Скрипт написан Вами, так? Значит, это Вы отправляете повторный запрос. А что не руками, а написанным так вот кодом - так это мелочи...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь в решении проблемы)) чем это мне поможет изменение в формулировки моей мысли, думаю меня поймут программисты... Вам спасибо за ответы...